# Getting error "skipping apparent function body" with simple header file

Tags: c++, function, if-statement

The error seems to happen at the first if statement. I can't seem to understand why this would be happening. The if is not in the global namespace as my googling has lead me to check.

I do apologize if I'm not posting correctly but this is my first post.

Thanks in advance. This is probably stupid simple but I'm currently learning.

```
#ifndef moveHare
#define moveHare

//Create new class for Hare movement roll
class moveHare
{
//Initialize variables to be used
    int hareMovement = 0;
    int hareRoll = rand() % 100 + 1;

private:
//if statements to compare the random int to the movement int 
//Error happens at first if statement.`enter code here`
    if (hareRoll > 50) {
        hareMovement = hareMovement + 3;
    }

    else if (hareRoll > 50 && hareRoll < 71) {
        hareMovement = hareMovement + 6;
    }
};

#endif
```

Comment: A class is not a function, you'll need to do some more reading.

Comment: You seem to have quite a few misunderstandings about C++. You should take a step back and systematically learn the language from a  good book.

Comment: That first comment just made me slap my head. You're exactly right. -_- thanks for the push in the right direction. Thanks George.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Baum. You're right, I do need to re-visit previous chapters. I was just trying to break up this app up into separate files ahead of my skillset.

I appreciate the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was creating a new class in the header file instead of declaring a function. This is the code corrected but not finished.

Thanks to George and Baum for showing me the obvious to a skilled set of eyes!

```
#pragma once

#ifndef movement
#define movement





int moveHare() {

        int hareMovement = 0;
        int hareRoll = rand() % 100 + 1;

        if (hareRoll > 50) {
            hareMovement = hareMovement + 3;
        }

        else if (hareRoll > 50 && hareRoll < 71) {
            hareMovement = hareMovement + 6;
    }
        return hareMovement;
}


#endif
```

Comment: Just as a side, `hareMovement = hareMovement + 3;` can be shortened to `hareMovement += 3;`. The second else will never be hit but I get the code isn't finished :)  Also, it doesn't really matter here but you may want to check out the [random](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/) header, it contains some very nice pseudo random number generators.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I knew it could be shortened but I didn't want to short hand this beginner stuff just yet. lol...

I also stumbled across the more accurate random number generating libraries but for this learning example I felt that rand() would work just fine!

Thanks again for the help. You might see another one of my simple answer posts in the future, hopefully a bit more advanced then. Cheers!

Comment: your `if-else if` will never enter the `else if` block, because if the first condition (`hareRoll > 50`) is false then also the second condition (`hareRoll > 50 && ...`) will be false. And you dont need `+=` to shorten it, you can simply write `hareMovement = 3` (or `hareMovement = 6`), because the initial value is `0`, ie you are adding to `0` anyhow.

Comment: and you dont need two scope guards. Either `#pragma once` or `#ifndef xyz #define xyz #endif` is sufficient. I would prefer the latter, because `#pragma once` isnt standard

Comment: Thanks for the feedback tobi303!

Yeah I had a few logical errors in some other if statements (fixed now!) but I stopped working on those as this was a more urgent issue until now.

The #pragama once was created automatically for me by VS and didn't know enough to safely delete it. Thanks for pointing that out! I'll go read more on "Scope Guards".

Comment: sry "scope guards" was a typo ;) It is called "header guard"

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you have solved the problem, but I just wanted to pitch in with an alternate solution. If you want to keep the class you declared in yout question, then you can do the following to fix the code:

```
 #ifndef moveHare
 #define moveHare

 //Create new class for Hare movement roll
 class MoveHare
 {
     private:
         int hareMovement = 0;
         int hareRoll = rand() % 100 + 1;

     public:
         int MoveTheHare(void);
 };

 #endif
```

Then you can define your function as follows:

```
int MoveHare::MoveTheHare(void)
{
    if (hareRoll > 50)
    {
        hareMovement = hareMovement + 3;
    }

    else if (hareRoll > 50 && hareRoll < 71)
    {
        hareMovement = hareMovement + 6;
    }

    return hareMovement;
}
```

I just wanted to take this question as an opportunity to post this method, even though it has been posted before. Hope this helps!

By the way, If there is anything that I did wrong in my code, or in my post, please inform me in the comments box.